# Is there a way to open a react Component(JSX) as another electron window in the electron app?

Tags: reactjs, electron

```
 // Component1.jsx

  const handleOpenImageModal = () => {
      console.log("check"); // visible
      ipcRenderer.send("open-my-component",);
   };


 return (
<ExpandArrowsAltIcon
            title={t("Image Inspection")}
            size={18}
            role="button"
            onClick={handleOpenImageModal}
          />
          <Modal>
           <MyComponent />
          </Modal>
)


// electron.js

function initApp() {
  ipcMain.on("openImageModal", (event, res) => {
    console.log("event", event);
    console.log("res", res);

    let myWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 600, height: 400 });
    console.log("myWindow: ", myWindow);
    myWindow.loadFile("MyComponent.jsx");
  });
}
```

[image]

In ExpandArrowsAltIcon, the handleOpenImageModal function is executed after the onClick event is called, and the ipcRender.send() function is called after the

I want to make sure that another electron window is created inside the electron.js file.

Currently, In the newly opened window, I don't see anything.
The component named MyComponent is the component for which the JSX is written.

As mentioned above, the code I wrote should render in the newly opened window.

#### Alternatives Considered

```
// electron.js

ipcMain.on("openImageModal", (event, res) => {
    console.log("event", event);
    console.log("res", res);

    let myWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 600, height: 400 });
    console.log("myWindow: ", myWindow);
    myWindow.loadFile("SegmentList.jsx");
  });
```

Comment: How do you show react in the first window?

Comment: @Konrad Do you mean the first window? That's the one with the graph in the picture I posted.

Comment: @Konrad An empty window with nothing in it is the window when you run handleOpenImageModal.